# not showing data in year dropdown in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dropdown

> this is my list to show data from string type list-

```
 List<Widget> _getYearList() {
    List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();

      for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
        list.add(Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            UtilString.years[index],
            //'$index',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ));
      }

      return list;

  }
```

> this is designing view -

```
SizedBox(width: 8),
                Text(
                  '${UtilString.year} : ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 52,
                  child: CupertinoPicker(
                    squeeze: 1.3,
                    itemExtent: 30,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    children: _getYearList(),
                    scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(
                      initialItem: _year - 1,
                    ),
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (item) {
                      setState(() {
                        _year = item + 1;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

> defind data

```
static final List years = <String>['1990', '1991', '1992', '1993 till 2020];
```

Comment: here year data in list not showing days and month showing properly.

Comment: can anyone suggest where doing wrong , why its not showing year data list in dropdown.

Comment: Please share the entire code

Comment: Hello @faroukosama in this code getyears method calling in class and in override method getting year, month and day values and i need to show same value of year as selected when dialog pop up.